# Reading lines from an InputStream without buffering

Tags: java, inputstream

Does Java have a simple method to read a line from an InputStream without buffering? BufferedReader is not suitable for my needs because I need to transfer both text and binary data through the same connection repeatedly and buffering just gets in the way.

Comment: Through binary data, you don't have lines, right? How about recognizing if your data is text or binary?

Comment: I do have them. The request starts with text lines describing it and sometimes is followed by binary data.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25215564/how-to-read-a-line-from-inputstream-without-buffering-the-input

Answer (score 7):

Eventually did it manually directly reading byte after byte from the InputStream without wrapping the InputStream. Everything I tried, like Scanner and InputStreamReader, reads ahead (buffers) the input :(

I guess I missed a some cases like \r.

```
public static String readLine(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    int c;
    for (c = inputStream.read(); c != '\n' && c != -1 ; c = inputStream.read()) {
        byteArrayOutputStream.write(c);
    }
    if (c == -1 && byteArrayOutputStream.size() == 0) {
        return null;
    }
    String line = byteArrayOutputStream.toString("UTF-8");
    return line;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the Scanner class: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

However, this **may** buffer the input if no newline characters are present:

> Since this method continues to search through the input looking for a line 
>   separator, it may buffer all of the input searching for the line to skip if no 
>   line separators are present.

Comment: Scanner buffers the input even past the newline :(

Comment: `Scanner` does buffers past the newline. I have a `StringReader` with seven lines and `Scanner` buffers them all in one shot.

Answer (score -3):

You may be better off reading the InputStream with a BufferedReader and appending the read lines to a String.

You can then manipulate the String as you wish without worrying about buffering.

Comment: The problem is that I have no control how BufferedReader reads input. It may read a line and a chunk of data PAST it. I don't want that.

Comment: @Ree, I think that Scanner only buffers backwards, not forward.